# SQL Server error: connection string property has not been initialized

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to export a the results of a SQL query into Excel. I found this YouTube video that shows how to achieve this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xCyZNY0isUM).

Following these instructions, I right click on my database, go to Tasks > Export. The wizard launches. I pass the initial page, and I get to the "Choose a data Source". I leave the default (.Net Framework Data Provider for Odbc) and click "Next". Here, I get this error message:

> connection string property has not been initialized (System.Data).

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can post an answer to your own question and mark it as resolved.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Change the source from the default to "SQL Native Client" which relies on Windows Authentication.

Answer (score 3):

Actually I had the same error but I changed the Choose Destination to native option (the last one) instead of doing "Choose Source" and apparently it worked.